# Referencing java resource files from ColdFusion

Tags: java, eclipse, coldfusion, properties-file

I am using a .jar file containing a `.properties` file in my CF code. However it seems unable to find the .properties file when run from CF.

My java code is:

```
    String key ="";
    String value ="";

    try {
        File file = new File("src/test.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fileInput);
        fileInput.close();

        Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
        while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
            value = properties.getProperty(key);
            //System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        key ="error";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        key ="error";
    }

    return(key + ": " + value);
```

I have my test.properties file in the project src folder, and make sure it is selected when compiling. When run from Eclipse it gives the expected keys and values. However when run from CF, I get the caught errors.

My  CF code is simply:

```
propTest = CreateObject("java","package.class"); 
testResults = propTest.main2();
```

Is there a special way to reference the .properties file so CF can access it, or do I need to include the file outside the .jar somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File("src/test.properties");

That is because you are using a physical file path, meaning it must exist on the physical disk, outside the jar. Also, it is a relative file path. Relative paths depends on your current context or directory. The working directory will be different in CF than in Eclipse. When you use the jar in CF, the relative path `"src/test.properties"` obviously resolves to a file that does not exist. Hence the error.

If you want to load a properties file contained *within* the jar, you need to use [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

```
// returns null if path does not exist
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.properties");
if (is != null) {
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(is);
   //... 
}
```

NB: `/` denotes the root of the package path and is also used as a path separtor

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the file reference from ColdFusion as a string rather then packaging up the file in to the jar.  Have the .properties file in a location that is accessable by the cf/java app.